# How does one validate html that's generated from JS running in the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

The page in question has very skeletal html sent over the wire to facilitate the building of a complicated UI in javascript.

I'm now encountering a strange browser compatibility issue that *feels* very much like I've got a markup problem somewhere on the page.

I've validated the page as it comes across the wire using the W3C tool and ensured there are no issues in that html. I've also tried validating the output of running on the browser console:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML
```

I find that the output of the above introduces lots of new issues, such as removing the trailing '/' in self closing tags.  This added noise is distracting, but it also makes me uneasy about validating this method.

How do you validate markup that's rendered client side?

Comment: `How do you validate markup that's rendered client side?` you don't. You just pray that it works. :) *Very* good question though! I'm not aware of any validators that do this.

Comment: Tell us about that strange compatibility issue.

Comment: Browsers aren't validators- read the innerHTML of any carefully marked up xhtml and you'll see that browsers ignore the close slashes, skip some closing tags and remove quotes and change case until the pages own mother wouldn't recognize it.

Answer (score 1):

When elements are created on the client, they are created correctly by the browser - there really isn't anything to validate. The only time you'd need to validate any markup is if you're actually assigning `outerHTML/innerHTML = some markup from the server`. If that's the case, just log out the results on your server and run them through the standard HTML validators.

Comment: or read it.. if you're doing this extensively you've probably got bigger issues to solve than broken validation of html..

Comment: But even if elements themselves are created correctly, they may not be nested correctly, or they may be missing mandatory attributes. For example, in HTML 4, the <img> tag must have alt specified. How do I find out if I accidentally forgot it somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

HTML documents are parsed by the browser into a DOM representation - the markup code itself isn't retained. When you create/modify elements via Javascript, they are also created via the DOM (or parsed into DOM objects, if using innerHTML/outerHTML assignment). So there isn't anything to validate, really, since your Javascript-generated page isn't stored as markup to begin with.

Retrieving HTML via innerHTML/outerHTML causes the browser to reconvert it, and browsers still generally do so with HTML syntax, not strictly XHTML syntax (e.g. regarding self-closing tags).

As far as working out the rendering issue (or maybe some messy/overlooked CSS, for example), you might consider using something like Firebug or Chrome's Developer Tools (or Firebug Lite for browsers other than Firefox and Chrome) - it lets you inspect the document structure and elements, select elements and see which CSS rules are applied to them, and visually inspect the box model. It might help you identify where your issue is.

And just in case, do you have a valid DOCTYPE declaration? Quirks mode can do strange things.

Comment: `innerHTML/outerHTML isn't good practice` why is that? It's sure faster the adding one after another element to the DOM (programming and processing time). Remember browsers are really good a parsing HTML, since it's their main task.

Comment: because in IE you don't have firebug to see whats going on. IE developer toolbar is horrid, and firebug lite is lacking.

Comment: @jim: Indeed, Firebug Lite is lacking - though it's still better than trying to fix a problem blindly, especially with Javascript-generated code.

@Thomas: Honestly, it's something I was told and read about briefly, but if I did find some justification I don't remember. My gut says it's messier and more error-prone (depending on where you get the HTML to insert), and the DOM is intended for such accesses/modifications. Apparently it's not a W3C standard either, though supported by major browsers. That and speed aside, if there's anything else to be said for/against, I'd be happy to hear it.

Comment: Of curse W3C is taking for ever to add it but it's happening with HTML5. However for a web dev that doesn't matter since it's supported by all browser of any relevance. Contra: script tags parsed through innerHTML are not executed in IE, doesn't work for parts of a table - you can't add a table row by appending it to the tables innerHTML - at least not cross browser. However dealing with those 2 bugs will prevent you from a lot of the DOMs minefield

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate a page why not access it, view source, copy it and use validate by direct input? It takes 3 clicks more than normal validation but... The other way is to host it somewhere and validate from there.